# Use of despite and regardless in one sentence

Tags: adverbs

Regardless is an adverb which implies:
in spite of everything, anyway, nevertheless, nonetheless, in any case, no matter what, despite everything, come what may

For instance: Despite her recent surgery she has been carrying on regardless.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/regardless

Question: Can we use despite and regardless in one sentence?

Comment: Why would you? It's redundant, saying the same thing twice.

Comment: @StoneyB true, that's why I was thinking that this example is wrong. I, therefore, quoted the source of the dictionary in which this example was given.

Comment: Actually, the source is [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/regardless), not TFD. Collins is methodologically driven by actual recorded use; that's admirable in many ways, but it occasionally winds up citing unedited colloquial uses that a careful writer would revise. Redundancy is not ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%20on%20regardless&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgo%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcarried%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwent%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgoes%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcarry%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpress%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpressed%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpassed%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpushed%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpush%20on%20regardless%3B%2Cc0) shows...

[image]

...the construction *[verb] on regardless* is commonly used with a variety of verbs such as *carry, press, go push, pass*, for the (metaphoric or literal) sense of *continue a current action or direction of movement [disregarding/ignoring any pressure to stop or change course]*.

As has been pointed out, there's nothing *inherently* wrong with "redundancy" in English (it's often used quite naturally to convey *emphasis*, for example). But noting in particular the significant increase for ***to carry on*** above, I'm inclined to say that specific combination has become something of a "fixed expression" in recent decades.

Precisely *because* it's become so common, the exact meaning of ***to carry on regardless*** has become somewhat vague in the minds of many speakers. Sometimes it just conveys a general sense of continuing to do something *diligently, industriously, laboriously, purposefully, resolutely,* with no particular allusion to ***in spite of*** [something that might stop the activity continuing].

Consequently, many native speakers wouldn't even notice the "repetition" in OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking specifically about this sentence in your link:

> Despite her recent surgery she has been carrying on regardless.

@StoneyB is correct; this is redundant. So, while you **can** use these together, the redundancy makes the sentence clumsy. So, dropping the 'regardless' becomes

> Despite her recent surgery she has been carrying on.

Which is more correct, but leaves a bit of a dangling ending. I think most speakers would say

> She has been carrying on despite her recent surgery.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have found another example where both despite and regardlessly have been used; ‘Despite the unenthusiastic reception that revelation received, Iron continued regardlessly; ‘yeah, well, I heard they're doing interviews for the South Street post.’’              http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/regardless